# Detect end of process from a sub-shell in ksh

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, ksh, pid

I launch a master script : master.ksh

I want to do some background task during the work of master.ksh.
For this, I created an script sourced at the beggining of master.ksh : slave.ksh with a $

```
./slave.ksh &
```

here is the code of slave.ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh

touch tmpfile
export thepid=$!
while [[`if [ -n "$thepid" ];fi`]]; do
    pwd >> tmpfile
    #other set of commands ...
    export thepid=$!
done
```

thepid is used to monitor the pid of the master.ksh, when master.ksh ends, I expect the end of the slave.ksh too and so, the exit of slave.ksh too

but I get an error from slave.ksh :

```
syntax error at line 5; fi unexpected
```

if I delete fi , I get another error. What is the good way to test $thepid ?

Answer (score 0):

...

I'm not sure where to begin. This is broken in at least three ways: shell variables don't work that way, if statements don't work that way, and conditionals don't work that way.

Here's one way to do it (tested on 93u+):

```
> cat master.ksh
#!/bin/ksh -eu

print master says hi

./slave.ksh&
sleep 5

print master says bye
> cat slave.ksh
#!/bin/ksh -eu

print slave says hi

while (($(ps oppid= $$)==$PPID))
do
    # work
    print slave working....
    sleep 1
done

print slave says bye
> ./master.ksh
master says hi
slave says hi
slave working....
slave working....
slave working....
slave working....
slave working....
master says bye
> slave says bye
```

This compares the `PPID` shell variable, which appears to be set at process launch, to the parent process id as returned by the linux `ps` tool, which returns the true current value. This works because when a process dies, any child processes it had have their parent process changed to `1` (`init`). So the slave works as long as its original PPID matches its current PPID, and then exits.